# Complex URL rewriting (without order)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have to rewrite a complex URL which can take from 0 to 20 different parameters.
The problem is that the parameters are in an undefined order (it depends on how user uses the site)

for example i can have :

```
www.site.com/page.php?A=x&B=x OR
www.site.com/page.php?B=x&A=x
```

and i would like these url to be rewritten as an unique URL like :

```
www.site.com/A-B.html
```

Is there a way to rewrite things like that ?
Thank you

Comment: U meant .htaccess rules or just with programming language ?

Comment: well all kind of rules that could work actually, i just want that my urls are shown correctly on google !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} A=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} B=
RewriteRule .* A-B.html [QSA,L]
```

Use [QSA] only if you are interested with the content of a= & b= etc...

Comment: i'm interested with the content of A and B, will it be usable ?

Comment: Yes, like `A-B.html?B=x&A=x`

Comment: Ok, and can i rewrite it like A-x-B-X.html ?

Comment: Not with the above .htaccess, that can be possible, but not so easy (if A & B) order change...

Comment: Yes that's what i thought, nevermind i'll do something with what you gave me

Comment: Great. So you will write a huge .htaccess files with all the possibilites, with 20 ore more condition? And you are not able to change the order of parameters. 8 lines of code (see my answer) could do it for you, even, in any order of parameters. Performance is nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with join function:

```
$params = array();
foreach ($_GET as $key => $val) {
    $params[] = $key;
}
if (count($params)) {
    header("Location: " . join("-", $params) . ".html");
    die();
}
```